# Access to the Path is denied in windows service

Tags: c#

I am using windows service to import data from excel to a database. after importing I want to move that file to backup folder.

```
private void moveFileToBackUpFolder(string filename, string _inputFilePath)
{
    try
    {
        WriteToFile("moveFileToBackUpFolder  " + filename);

        string sourcePath = _inputFilePath;
        string targetPath = _inputFilePath + "\\Backup Files";

        string sourceFile = Path.Combine(sourcePath, filename);
        string destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, filename);

        if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        }

        File.Move(sourceFile, destFile);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteToFile("moveFileToBackUpFolder execption  " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

but i am getting access to the path is denied.
Same code i am using in windows form and it is working.
I am using windows server 2016 .

Can anyone help me tosolve this issue.

Comment: are you sure the account you are running the program with has access to move the file "from" source "to" target? is the path valid? Have you run debugger to see which step it fails on?

Comment: Can you check which user is running the windows service ? `Go to Services > Properties (Your service) > Log On`. Does that user have access to the path ?

Comment: Its a permissions thing, the service will not be running as you by default. In your installer you can probably configure it to use the use who installed it, or make sure that the folders involved grant access to the service user.

Comment: @stud3nt.  changed user in log on. now it is working .Thank you

Comment: great, I have added it as an answer. Please upvote and Mark it as answer if it has helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check which user is running the windows service ? `Go to Services > Properties (Your service) > Log On`. Does that user have access to the path ?

Add the user which has access and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Check that directory or file has proper permission. Below given reason stop to move file from one location to another.

1. The caller does not have the required permission.
2. The file is an file that is in use.
3. Path is a directory.
4. Path specified read-only file.